# SCORM 2004 3rd Edition completion status not saving

Tags: scorm

i have a problem with my cmi.completion_status. I have a SCORM 2004 3rd Edition  course that runs under SABA LMS, the course works fine, and all my progress is storing correctly, but whenever i try to set the 'cmi.completion_status' to 'completed' nothing happens. The rest of the data is stored, for example the same way i set the completion status i set the score.raw and in the end result i have the raw set to 100, but the completion is missing:

```
cmi.score.raw = 100
cmi.score.max = 100
cmi.score.min = 0
cmi.score.scaled = 1
```

I am very new with SCORM and i have no idea what more info you will need to help me, so ask me for more information if needed.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Its possible if you are using a completion threshold in your packaging (imsmanifest.xml) the LMS is managing this for you.
cmi.completion_status is based off cmi.progress_measure in this situation.

So if completion threshold is 1 (or some decimal inbetween 0-1) you'd also need to set cmi.progress_measure to 1 to be 'completed'.

See adlcp:completionThreshold to see if its present in your imsmanifest.xml.

Beyond that, you'll want to check for any SCORM Errors that may be triggered when you set your completion status.  That may shed some light on why the status is not sticking, or you could also have something reverting it back on exit or submission.

GL